# Stuck using Python 3 List

Tags: python, list

having some problems with Python (3) Lists.

```
def initLocations():
    locName = ["The Town","The Blacksmith Hut"]
    locDesc = ["A small but beautiful town. You've lived here all your life.",     "There are many shops here, but the Blacksmith Hut is the most intricate."]
```

This is at the top of the script. Later on, it is called by this:

```
initLocations()
```

Then about 4 lines later:

```
while currentLoc<20:
    initLocations()
    print("Type 'Help' for advice on what to do next.")
    passedCommand = input("?: ")
    mainProcess(passedCommand)
```

More info here: http://pastebin.com/5ib6CJ4g

Keep getting the error

```
print("Left: " + locName[currentLoc-1])
NameError: name 'locName' is not defined
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Python array's have a more elegant name called `list`

Comment: `locNam` only exists in `initLocations()` so if you use it outside the function it will give you that error. Just declare the lists just outside the while loop . Unless something happens in `initLocations()` to the lists it is a bit pointless using it

Comment: You also need to make sure you have 20 items in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables defined within a function are local to that function. They do not leak out into the calling scope (which is a good thing). If you want the function to make things available, you need to *return* them. For example:

```
def initLocations():
    locName = […]
    locDesc = […]
    return locName, locDesc
```

This will make the function return a two-tuple containing the list of names and the list of descriptions. When calling the function, you will then need to capture the values and save them to variables again. For example:

```
locName, locDesc = initLocations()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just calling a function does not create the variable in the outer scope. You will have to make them `global`, however it is a very bad way of doing stuff. You need to `return` it from the function. That is in `initLocations()` you need to have a statement `return locName` and when you call it you need to use `locName = initLocations()`. Given that you have two variables, you will need to send them as a tuple

Demo

```
def initLocations():
    locName = ["The Town","The Blacksmith Hut"]
    locDesc = ["A small but beautiful town. You've lived here all your life.",     "There are many shops here, but the Blacksmith Hut is the most intricate."
    return (locName,locDesc)
```

and then

```
while currentLoc<20:
    locName,locDesc = initLocations()
    print("Type 'Help' for advice on what to do next.")
    passedCommand = input("?: ")
    mainProcess(passedCommand)
```

This is called *Tuple packing - Sequence Unpacking*

**Small Note**

As Padraic mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137283/stuck-using-python-3-list/28137342?noredirect=1#comment44646575_28137342) 
It is quite useless to have a function to just declare the 2 lists (Unless you have to do that)

You can instead do,

```
locName = ["The Town","The Blacksmith Hut"]
locDesc = ["A small but beautiful town. You've lived here all your life.",     "There are many shops here, but the Blacksmith Hut is the most intricate."
while currentLoc<20:        
    print("Type 'Help' for advice on what to do next.")
    passedCommand = input("?: ")
    mainProcess(passedCommand)
```

Which is a better way

Comment: It is a bit pointless using a function to store two lists though,  declaring the lists in the while would make more sense. Also if the OP tried to change the list by calling the function the changes would not persist.

Comment: I actually meant just outside the while ;)

Comment: In either alternative you show of creating them, the two variables will still end up being globals.

Comment: yep,   just declaring/creating the list once and if the OP wants to maniuplate it in the while loop the changes will persist

Comment: @martineau, you can pass the lists to the function which would make more sense than creating a function just to return two lists. Or at least just create them in the function  where you want to use them.

Comment: @Padraic: Of course you could -- I was only pointing out to Bhargav that what's in this answer still creates "very bad" global variables (which is what the OP incorrectly thought should happen with their code).

Comment: @martineau Sir, Sorry for using the words (very bad). We don't know if this whole code is inside another function :) ... Then these variables will not be `global`

Comment: @Bhargav: No apology for the words is necessary (see [_Global Variables Considered Harmful_](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesConsideredHarmful)). I was just pointing that after saying that, you're then doing it. Note that in this case we do in fact know that they're global because we **can** see all the code -- there's a [link](http://pastebin.com/5ib6CJ4g) to it in the question (see lines 73-77 at the end).

Comment: @martineau Sir, Thank you for the correction. I am now in a dilemma, Is it possible to do this without making them global? (If so, please do reply), as I am not able to think of any other way of doing it. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Bhargav: Well, an object-oriented way to avoid them would be to make them instance attributes of a `Game` class that had an `initLocations(self)` method which initialized the instance attributes `self.locName` and `self.locDesc`. This could also be done the class's `__init__()` method (or a call made to the other method). If you look at the whole code, all of the other global-level variables could be handled that way and all the functions made into class methods. The only global thing would be one instance of the new `Game` application class.

Comment: @martineau Sir, Thanks for that. I changed the code to introduce classes, and added the part after the comment as a main function and left the loop as it is. It does work as expected and doesn't create global variables. But now the other part, all `print` statements should be moved out of the class. So we should have 2 classes and a call-back. Is it the correct way of doing so?

Comment: @Bhargav: What code are you changing? Regardless, the `print` statements (and `input` function call) _could_ be made part of a class method, say one called `Run()`, and the value stored in `self.name`. Alternatively, it could be left out and another global  variable introduced to temporarily hold the value. This could then be passed as an argument to the `Game` constructor (or the `Run()` method) , so doing so wouldn't be all that bad since the global variable's use was severely restricted. If you have further questions I suggest you create a new SO question out of them.

Comment: @martineau Nope, no questions of my own Sir. The only doubt was whether it is apt to have `print` statements inside a class.

Comment: @martineau Sorry for wasting your valuable time Sir, I've learnt a lot from this today.

Answer (score 0):

The scope inside of `initLocations` is not global. Values created inside of that function's scope will not be available in outer, enclosing levels of scope, unless the variable is declared as `global` or returned as a value by the function.

The second approach is highly preferable:

```
def initLocations():
    locName = ["The Town","The Blacksmith Hut"]
    locDesc = ["A small but beautiful town. You've lived here all your life.",     
               "There are many shops here, but the Blacksmith Hut is the most intricate."]
    return locName, locDesc
```

Then later when you call the function:

```
locName, locDesc = initLocations()
```